# Javascript: Get a reference from JSON object with traverse

Tags: javascript, object, traversal

I need to get a reference from JSON object, the code just following:

```
var Tree = {
    data: {
        0: {
            pk: 1,
        },
        1: {
            pk: 2,
        },
        2: {
            pk: 3,
            children: {
                0: {
                    pk: 11,
                },
                1: {
                    pk: 22,
                },
                2: {
                    pk: 33,
                },
            },
        },
    },

    traverse: function(data, pk) {
        for (i in data) {
            // console.log(data[i]);
            if(data[i].pk && data[i].pk == pk)
                return data[i];

            if (typeof(data[i].children) == 'object')
                this.traverse(data[i].children, pk);
        };
    },
}
```

The code works very well when traverse the top level items:

```
>>> Tree.traverse(Tree.data, 1);
Object {pk=1}
```

But broken when get the child element:

```
>>> Tree.traverse(Tree.data, 22);
undefined
```

I'm very strange why it's this behavior, when you uncomment the '// console.log(data[i]);' line you will see the object is got but didn't returned.

Any idea about it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't put `return` before `this.traverse(data[i].children, pk);`.

---

**EDIT:**

```
var Tree = {
    data: {
        0: {
            pk: 1,
        },
        1: {
            pk: 2,
        },
        2: {
            pk: 3,
            children: {
                0: {
                    pk: 11,
                },
                1: {
                    pk: 22,
                },
                2: {
                    pk: 33,
                },
            },
        },
    },

    traverse: function(data, pk) {
        for (var i in data) {
            // console.log(data[i]);
            if(data[i].pk && data[i].pk == pk)
                return data[i];

            if (typeof(data[i].children) == 'object') {
                var retVal = this.traverse(data[i].children, pk);
                if (typeof retVal!='undefined') {//here was the logical problem,there might be more than one
                                                 //object, we can't return the result of traversing first one.
                                                 //So we will check, if no return, we go on searching
                    return retVal;
                }
            }

        };
    },
};

alert(Tree.traverse(Tree.data, 1).pk);
alert(Tree.traverse(Tree.data, 22).pk);
```

check live here: http://jsfiddle.net/rq4LK/

Comment: Could you give me the full sample code ? I tried but didn't make effect.

Comment: @K K, I edited it, check the changes, it has a comment to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but you are creating a global variable in your `for` loop. Try `for(var i in data)` instead and then report back please.

In case this is not the whole object and you have a property with a key (like `3: ...`) in the parent `Object` literal that does not exist in the `children` child property, it will obviously return `undefined`, as there is no such property by that key.

**Edit:** As per your comment, this might also be a problem with function scope as you are using **tail recursion** to iterate over an object with multiple layers. 
Thus, try to put the current object reference outside the function scope as you would do in any javascript language construct that requires a dynamic reference:

```
var current = null , match = null ;

function traverse() {

    var data = arguments[0] ;
    var pk = arguments[1] ;

        for(var i in data) {

                current = data[i] ; /* DEBUG */console.log( current.toSource() ) ; //!! Object.prototype.toSource() requires a W3 compatible browser (like FF)

                if(current.pk !== undefined && current.pk === pk) return current ;
                else if( typeof current.children === "object") traverse(current.children, pk);

         }
}

match = traverse(data,pk) ;
```

**Edit 2:** Flawed logic on my part. Try this instead:

```
var match = null ;

function traverse() {

    var data = arguments[0] ;
    var pk = arguments[1] ;

    var current = null ;

        for(var i in data) {

                current = data[i] ; /* DEBUG */console.log( current.toSource() ) ; //!! Object.prototype.toSource() requires a W3 compatible browser (like FF)

                if(current.pk !== undefined && current.pk === pk) match = current ; //!! if there is a match set the variable match to the current object
                else if( typeof current.children === "object") traverse(current.children, pk); //!! else use recursion to test a child property if present

         }

}
```

Using that, if your object contains the specified property `match` won't be `null` and will contain the matching object or child object.

Comment: I tried <code>for (var i in data)</code> but doesn't work, it still response <code>undefined</code>. For your 2nd section: I think the data is a reference here(It same as point in C language). When <code>this.traverse(data[i].children, pk);</code> it's pointed to the 2nd level of the tree.But thank you for your response all the same.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have a most same idea this morning but haven't tried yet. :-)

Comment: No worries, pleasure to be able to help out. :-)